# May I only parse one node in xml at one time in sql server?

Tags: sql, xml, parsing, nodes

If I have following xml:

```
<Main>
  <Group>
    <Insert />
  </Group>

  <Group>
    <Insert />
  </Group>

  ...
</Main>
```

I know that if I use `openxml(@xml, 'Main/Group/Insert',1)`, I will parse all `<Insert>`.

Is there a way I can read only one group node, parse its Insert node and then read the next group node and parse its Insert node?

Comment: (Include an actual XML snippet?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenXML or newer XML datatype and XPath treat the XML as a table, extracting and treating the results as multiple rows in one go.

What you are asking is equivalent to, for a normal SQL Server table, can you select one record, then read the next record?  Of course *- such as using cursors or WHILE loop -*, but why?

Consider what you want to do with it, and you will soon come around to treating it properly as a dataset and getting the parsed results as records, and applying SET logic to the values you retrieve from it.

Comment: What I want to do exactly is I want to let one procedure A parse the whole xml and read only one group node, pass this node (as its original xml format - you can consider it as a smaller xml file) to another procedure B. Then A pass the 2nd group node in xml format to B...